# Blinking when changing image with notifyListeners()

Tags: flutter, dart

Save data using `provider` package and update UI with `notifyListeners()`.

```
int _nEnsembleCode = 0;
  int get nEnsembleCode => _nEnsembleCode;

 Future<void> changeEnsembleCode(int nButtonIndex) async {
    _nEnsembleCode = nButtonIndex;
    notifyListeners();
  }
```

Change the image with `nEnsembleCode` data value.

```
return Container(
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
  image: DecorationImage(
    fit: BoxFit.fill,
    image: ensembleCode.nEnsembleCode == 2 ?
             AssetImage('assets/images/buttons/alto_on_button.png') : 
             AssetImage('assets/images/buttons/alto_off_button.png'),
       ),
    ),
 );
```

The data is also changed normally and the image is also changed normally.

However, flickering occurs when the image is changed. Is there any way to solve this problem???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you have a conditional image, and want to avoid flickering, you should use the `Image` widget, because it supports `gaplessPlayback`, change your code to:

```
return Container(
  alignment: Alignment.center,
  child: Image.asset(
    fit: BoxFit.fill,
    ensembleCode.nEnsembleCode == 2
    ? 'assets/images/buttons/alto_on_button.png'
    : 'assets/images/buttons/alto_off_button.png',
    gaplessPlayback: true,
  ),
 );
```

this should fix your issue